# What's the fastest way to have someone reviewing your own questions?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

How does the reviewing system exactly works on Stack Overflow?

I mean, I've seen countless times people who are proficient in English like @Peter Mortensen, who has reviewed many of my questions very fast and well. That's just awesome!

Now, I'd like to know whether is possible to ask explicitely this proficient people to review my very often "low quality" questions. If it's so, what's the proper way to do it? Also, would it be possible to reward such a good people's effort somehow?

To be honest, I think it's a really good system the one implemented on Stack Overflow to review stuff but I'd like to know more about it to make an efficient usage of it every time I feel my question could be improved by some experts out there.

Comment: Well that might com across the wrong way to some people. it might seem like your trying to find the best editors in the SO comunnity, and constantly bug them to review your poor questions. Nevertheless a feature like this, would be extremely helpful. Possible something such as a review queue for questions.

Comment: @Mr.goosberry That's not my intention at all. I wouldn't like neither bugging anybody nor finding the best reviewers from SO. I just want to know what's my best chance (fastest way) to speed up the review of my unfortunately poor questions.

Comment: so this is not a feature request? AFAIK there is no review queue for questions. I assumed that this was a feature you wanted to implement.

Comment: @Mr.goosberry may be different on Stack Overflow but isn't there a review que for first posts and low quality posts which includes both questions and answers?

Comment: @BPL the fastest way is to see how your previous questions have been edited and use that to improve new questions yourself

Comment: @Memor-X yes, I believe your right. I believe there is a review queue for first time questions an answers. But BPL seemed to be a pretty I experienced user, so that might no apply to him.

Comment: @Mr.goosberry There is triage, Help and Improvement, Close votes, and Reopen votes, all specifically for questions, then the first posts queue also has questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seeking help from particular SO users (either answers, comments or edits) is generally frowned upon.

I think the best way to get particular a user to review your post is posting very high quality questions in a narrow enough set of tags that the user is following. This would only work if you learn from edits - I'm quite sure if editor start seeing patterns of the same errors you quickly get into "ignore those people" list.

More practical suggestion would be to ask someone around you to proofread your posts (free or paid in some way).

Comment: From my short experience on this site I've seen almost every little minor detail is frowned upon, I guess that's the power of internet anonymity. If this is not so I don't understand why my polite question has got so many downvotes. I'm starting to think the site is kind of broken. In any case, thanks for your answer, points taken

Comment: @BPL votes on META are different than on main site. Generally they express approval/disapproval of request and not quality of the question. You can read the [lowest voted](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?page=488&sort=votes) questions on META to see that there is nothing wrong with such questions - just idea proposed in them did not get community approval.